# Can any Hermitian operator be expressed as the squared absolute value of a non-Hermitian operator?

Tags: operator-algebras

Say I have a Hermitian operator, $H^{\dagger} = H$.

Does there always exist at least one operator that may or may not be Hermitian, $O^{\dagger} \neq O$, such that:

$$
H = OO^{\dagger}
$$

It makes sense to me that this should be the case, since I can't imagine what a counterexample would look like, but also it would be nice to know that a proof exists.

Comment: If there exists such and $O$, then $H$ must be nonnegative definite.

Comment: Okay, grand. In my case $H$ is the number operator so the set of eigenvalues is just $\mathbb{N}$. Thanks!

Comment: For a non-negative Operator you get such a decomposition by the square root of the operator, however this I'd not the absolute value but the square of $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operators of the form $OO^\dagger$ are precisely the Hermitian operators with non-negative spectrum (often called "positive operators").

An easy counterexample in $M_2(\mathbb C)$ would be $$H=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},$$ with eigenvalues $1,-1$.